# What do these options in the game.cfg mean?

Tags: league-of-legends

In `C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config`, there is a file called `game.cfg` which stores the configuration of the game. While most options are easy to understand (for instance, `ShowSpellCost=1` does what it does -- shows the cost of each spell), I fail to understand a few others. Some options include:

- in `General`

  - `ShowGodray`
  - `BindSysKeys`
- in `HUD`

  - `DisableMouseCaptureDebugger`
  - `ShowChampionIndicator`
  - `ItemShopItemDisplayMode`
  - `ItemShopStartPane`
    etc.

Is there a list of what each option mean, preferably official?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ShowGodray` is the setting where when you center the screen on your champion using Space, it shows a light around your champion or an indicator or something. https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/4vc4np/what_does_showgodrays_option_in_gamecfg_do/

Comment: And here's an example of a champion indicator using `ShowChampionIndicator` (see the ring around Garen in the images): http://www.surrenderat20.net/2013/09/96-pbe-update-2-garen-vu.html#more

Answer (score 1):

These are the definition of some of the commands:

> BindSysKeys

This will remember your custom keybindings. For example: ctrl+f shows/hides your fps.

> ItemShopItemDisplayMode

This will remember how your shop should look lie, due to the option of how you want to showcase your shop. It can be shown with all the items in squares. Or under subtitles like: Recommended, Early Game, Late Game etc.